# Why does an image transition affect my animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have constant animation running on an image view:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:dur
                      delay:curAnim.delay
                    options:(params)
                 animations:^{
                     self.view.layer.opacity = curAnim.opacity;
                     self.view.center = curAnim.center;
                     CGAffineTransform tr = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(curAnim.rotation);
                     tr = CGAffineTransformScale(tr, curAnim.scale, curAnim.scale);
                     self.view.transform = tr;

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];
```

Then, as the constant animation is running I want to transition to another image:

```
-(void)transitionToImage:(UIImage*)image duration:(CGFloat)duration
{
    UIImageView* iv = (UIImageView*)self.view;

    iv.image = image;

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = duration;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;

    [iv.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"transition"];
}
```

However, when I transition, there are now 2 views, one moving and one not, instead of the transition happening on my image view.

I tried various methods of transitioning but all yield the same problem.

How could I make it so I can transition and continue the current running animation?

Comment: Try adding it to the `presentationLayer` instaed. `[iv.layer.presentationLayer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"transition"];`

Comment: @JackWu Testing this, it seems the same effect.

Comment: @Milo, on my test project it worked on a single animation that looped. It seems you are chaining animations, and I wonder if that is the problem. Have you tried using a keyframe animation?

Comment: @LeoNatan CAKeyframe Animation API is ridiculously complex so that is why I rolled this out... The obvious solution is to have 2 UIViews that follow each other and both get animated and ease into each other, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Don't use `CAKeyFrame` API, use the new `UIView` key frame animation: `animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`. It's very simple to use actually.

Comment: @LeoNatan I noticed that API, but this app Im making has to run on ios 6.

Comment: It seems this is how fade/crossfade is implemented. I changed the transition to "rotate from left" and it seems to work as expected. Crossfade takes two snapshots from before and after and this is what you see.

Comment: @LeoNatan Yeah that's what I suspected too.

Comment: One more idea for you to try - move all your animations to CAAnimation. But I doubt it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Core Animation for both animations

```
CABasicAnimation *posAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
posAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(250, 250)];
posAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:self.imageView.layer.position];
posAnimation.duration = 3;
posAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
posAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[self.imageView.layer addAnimation:posAnimation forKey:nil];

CABasicAnimation *imgAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
imgAnim.fromValue = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1"].CGImage;
imgAnim.toValue = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2"].CGImage;
imgAnim.duration = 3;
imgAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
imgAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[self.imageView.layer addAnimation:imgAnim forKey:nil];
```

CoreAnimation (CATransition) does not really change the properties. [UIView animateWithDuration: ...] does. So CATransition don't care where the current position is. It grabs your image at the position where the animation starts and perform your transition only on the "presentationLayer" (not on the layer itself) which is always on the same position.

**Update:**

```
CABasicAnimation *scaleAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
scaleAnim.fromValue = @1;
scaleAnim.toValue = @2;
scaleAnim.duration = 3;
scaleAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
scaleAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[self.imageView.layer addAnimation:scaleAnim forKey:nil];


CABasicAnimation *rotAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
rotAnim.fromValue = @0;
rotAnim.toValue = @(M_PI);
rotAnim.duration = 3;
rotAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
rotAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[self.imageView.layer addAnimation:rotAnim forKey:nil];
```

Comment: What about rotation and scaling though?

Comment: just do it ;o) (see Update)